# Converting timestamp to time ago in PHP

Tags: php, timestamp

i have this timestamp php code which doesn't display the right time. it always shows 8 hours ago when the time is suppose to be minutes ago.

```html
  /**
  * Convert a timestap into timeago format
  * @param time
  * @return timeago
  */  

    public static function timeago($time, $tense = "ago"){
      if(empty($time)) return "n/a";
       $time=strtotime($time);
       $periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
       $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");
       $now = time();
         $difference = $now - $time;
         for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
           $difference /= $lengths[$j];
         }
         $difference = round($difference);
         if($difference != 1) {
           $periods[$j].= "s";
         }
       return "$difference $periods[$j] $tense ";
    }
```

i don't really understand why it doesn't work properly

Comment: what is the input and what output are you expecting ?

Comment: use carbon dependency, it will make it easyer for you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a function i wrote for you.

It uses [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php), so PHP version must be >= 5.3.0.

Read the comments in function to understand how it works.

```
function timeago($time, $tense='ago') {
    // declaring periods as static function var for future use
    static $periods = array('year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second');

    // checking time format
    if(!(strtotime($time)>0)) {
        return trigger_error("Wrong time format: '$time'", E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    // getting diff between now and time
    $now  = new DateTime('now');
    $time = new DateTime($time);
    $diff = $now->diff($time)->format('%y %m %d %h %i %s');
    // combining diff with periods
    $diff = explode(' ', $diff);
    $diff = array_combine($periods, $diff);
    // filtering zero periods from diff
    $diff = array_filter($diff);
    // getting first period and value
    $period = key($diff);
    $value  = current($diff);

    // if input time was equal now, value will be 0, so checking it
    if(!$value) {
        $period = 'seconds';
        $value  = 0;
    } else {
        // converting days to weeks
        if($period=='day' && $value>=7) {
            $period = 'week';
            $value  = floor($value/7);
        }
        // adding 's' to period for human readability
        if($value>1) {
            $period .= 's';
        }
    }

    // returning timeago
    return "$value $period $tense";
}
```

don't forget to set timezone you work

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

use it

```
echo timeago('1981-06-07'); // 34 years ago
echo timeago(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')); // 0 seconds ago
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your timezone is not set right! Before getting the time, try setting the default timezone:

```
date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier )
```

[More about the function on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php/)

[List of Supported Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php/)

Comment: this is for the timezone `    "timezone" => date_default_timezone_get(),`

Comment: @DarkSterix I am not sure I understand what you mean. What you wrote is the function for **getting** the timezone. What I wrote is for **setting** the timezone. If you get the timezone and the timezone returned is false, then you get the time for a different timezone than yours.

Comment: since the function returns the right timezone, i don't understand why it starts with 8 hours ago instead of 1 or 2 hours, or minutes

Comment: @DarkSterix Add to your question the part where you also call the function and all.

Comment: ` <p><small><?php echo e("Published") ?> <strong><?php echo Main::timeago($post->date) ?></strong></small></p>'

Comment: @DarkSterix I mean, edit your original question post, and write what your input is (the actual string/data, not just $post->date) and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
function time_elapsed($datetime, $full = false) {

$now = time();
$ago = strtotime($datetime);

$diff   = $now - $ago; 

$string = array(
    'year'  => 31104000,
    'month' => 2592000,
    'week'  => 604800,
    'day'   => 86400,
    'hour'  => 3600,
    'minute'=> 60,
    'second'=>  1
);

$data = array();

foreach ($string as $k => $v) {

    if($diff > $v){
        $count    = round($diff / $v);
        $data[$k] = $count . (($count > 1) ? ' ' . $k .'s' : ' ' . $k);
        $diff     = $diff % $v;
    }
}

if (!$full) $data = array_slice($data, 0, 1);
   return $data ? implode(', ', $data) . ' ago' : 'just now';
}

echo time_elapsed('2016-01-18 13:07:30', true); 
      // 2 years, 1 month, 2 weeks, 6 days, 25 seconds ago
echo time_elapsed('2016-01-18 13:07:30'); 
     // 2 years ago
```

Answer (score 0):

### a good and short way

just pass your timestamp date to the below function:

```
function getTimeAgoFormat($timestamp)
{
    $strTime = ["second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade"];
    $length = [60, 60, 24, 30, 12, 10, 10];
    $currentTime = time();
    if ($currentTime >= $timestamp) {
        $diff = time() - $timestamp;
        for ($i = 0; $diff >= $length[$i] && $i < count($length) - 1; $i++) {
            $diff /= $length[$i];
        }
        $diff = round($diff);
        if ($strTime[$i] === 'day') {
            if ($diff > 7) {
                $diff = round($diff / 7);
                return $diff . " " . "week" . ($diff > 1 ? "s" : "");
            }
        }
        return $diff . " " . $strTime[$i] . ($diff > 1 ? "s" : "");
    }
}
```